# Where to find remaining Boldgrid code in WP database?

Tags: plugins, troubleshooting

I have a boldgrid installation gone wrong. 
To remedy it, I uninstalled all boldgrid elements from the WP interface (not via boldgrid as is required, because I didn't even check to look for such a requirement). After uninstalling everything and flushing the browser cache, I tried a reinstall--first from my host (I'm on a VPS so on my  own, which is fine), using Softaculus.

This brought the site straight back in to 500 internal server error, and then a plugin fatal error (included below). deactivated every plugin again, and uninstalled every part of Boldgrid. Flushed cache.

I then downloaded the Boldgrid plugins, and manually uploaded just the troublesome plugin, Inspirations. This gave the very same fatal error. When inspecting the PHP code the error referred to, it looked like a license mismatch, where I have the free version, the plugin listed the premium version.

So I uninstalled Boldgrid again, and head over to their site for some clues. On boldgrid Central I found that despite the uninstall Boldgrid was still connected to my Wordpress.org installation, as well as my Wordpress.com identity.

Three hooks linked the website to the solution. I tried replacing my license key, thinking this would either disconnect the hooks or give me an e-mail with where to manually place the correct key in my WP database. No such luck.

So I did what insane people do, try the same thing again, install Boldgrid. Same error. I'm talking to their support about disconnecting their solution from my site and resetting my account, but just in case it a) doesn't happen, or b) something else goes wrong:

QUESTION: Can anyone steer me to where in my WP database the hooks to Boldgrid reside so I can remove them? ALL themes and components have been completely uninstalled. I'm looking for any rogue code that has been left behind and is causing the crash, in addition to the website hooks. I'll attach a screenshot of the Boldgrid dashboard to show what I am referring to. I'd be grateful for any hints on where to look.

PS: I'm a beginning developer, but not afraid to read or edit PHP code. I've been using Wordpress since 2007.

> **Error code, with privacy / identifying parts of path removed:** 
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Boldgrid\Library\Library\License' not found in /home/Userxx/MyWebsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/boldgrid-inspirations/vendor/boldgrid/boldgrid-inspirations-premium/src/Premium/Attribution.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /home/Userxx/MyWebsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/boldgrid-inspirations/boldgrid-inspirations.php(64): Boldgrid\Inspirations\Premium\Attribution->__construct() #1 /home/Userxx/MyWebsite.com/wp/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(1897): include('/home/Userxx/co...') #2 /home/Userxx/MyWebsite.com/wp/wp-admin/plugins.php(178): plugin_sandbox_scrape('boldgrid-inspir...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/Userxx/MyWebsite.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/boldgrid-inspirations/vendor/boldgrid/boldgrid-inspirations-premium/src/Premium/Attribution.php on line 39

SCREENSHOT OF BOLDGRID DASHBOARD: 
[image: Boldgrid Dash Screenshot]

Thanks again for any help you can give.

Comment: Note: I guess I broke the rules--I asked about a plugin, and a Wordpress Specific question. If there is another forum where these are allowed, please do let me know.

Comment: You should be asking Boldgrid...

Comment: Thank you Jacob.I am. To clarify, what I am asking here, is in which files do typically license hooks reside. If I know that, I can use an editor to search the code and remedy the issue. I can search every document on the site, but I was hoping to narrow it down. Thanks for any direction you or anyone are able to give. :)

Comment: Again, that’s something you’d need to ask Boldgrid. There is no standard file in WordPress where “license hooks” reside.

Comment: yeh, sorry but totally off topic in several levels. as to were to look, wordpress do not have any "licensing" type of system support and every plugin and theme invents its own, so it is just impossible to guess

Comment: Thank you Mark. That explains it. I thought there were standard files to link to. Without that there surely is no way you or anyone can tell at all. I appreciate the help. Now for another question, how do I close this topic?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this, for Boldgrid or any other Wordpress plugin. The table, is WP-options; or--[yourPrefix]-options.

Some plugins leave data behind after uninstall.

This post has a pretty good tutorial on removing the entries.

[Some Plugin Settings Are Kept After Removal and Reinstall of the Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75395/some-plugin-settings-are-kept-after-removal-and-reinstall-of-the-plugin)